# Using VBA to change graph colors

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I have a report that consists of several tabs with the same data for a different person. When I have to modify the sheets I usually delete all but one sheet and modify this one, then copy the sheet for the other persons (Using a VBA script).

Unfortunatly in the copying proces the graphs in the report change colors. So I thought i need a VBA code that loops through al the sheets and graphs and correct the colors.

Havent got it working yet so who can give me a hand. I use the following code:

```
Sub Kleur()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("user1")
Dim objCht As ChartObject

For Each objCht In ws.ChartObjects
objCht.Chart.SeriesCollection([Doelstelling]).Interior.Color = RGB(1, 1,     1)
Next objCht


End Sub
```

Or is there a way to copy the sheets without the color change?

I use the following command to copy the sheets:

```
      Sheets("user1").Copy After:=Sheets(3)
```

Comment: When I use the line     objCht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Interior.Color = RGB(1, 1,     1) the first of the series changes color but when I use 2 Seriescollection(2) it does not work on the second series

Comment: Hmm seems like I picked the wrong series number. Is it possible to use a series name?